# Flattening a list

Tags: list, prolog

Trying to solve exercise 07 from http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/

I've started with a single iteration which looks like following

```
my_flatten1([], []).
my_flatten1([[A|T]|U], [A|V]) :-
   append(T, U1, V),
   my_flatten1(U, U1).
my_flatten1([A|T], [A|U]) :-
   not(is_list(A)),
   my_flatten1(T, U).

is_flat(A) :-
   my_flatten1(A, A).
```

it seems to work just fine for the following set of queries

```
my_flatten1([a, [b, [c, d], e]], X).
my_flatten1(X, [a, b, c]).
my_flatten1(X, [a|T]).
my_flatten1(X, [a, b, A]).
my_flatten1([a, X], M).
my_flatten1([a|X], M).

is_flat([a|X]).
is_flat([a,[c]|X]).
is_flat([F,[c]|X]).

my_flatten1(A, B).
my_flatten1([A], B).
my_flatten1([[A]], B).
my_flatten1([[a|A]], B).
my_flatten1([a|A], B).
my_flatten1([X|B], [1,2,3,4]).
my_flatten1([[a,c|D]|X], [a|B]).
```

However I wasn't successful to build `my_flatten` based on `my_flatten1`. There's always some queries that fail or end up in endless loops, or produce just one, most obvious result.

Edit to clarify what I am after, for example I can call `my_flatten1` with a variable as a first argument in order to distribute brackets:

```
?- my_flatten1(X, [a, b]).
X = [[a], [b]] ;
X = [[a], b] ;
X = [[a, b]] ;
X = [a, [b]] ;
X = [a, b].
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are aware that the 99 Prolog problems contain solutions when you click on the problem title?

Anyways, `my_flatten` looks, for example, like following:

```
my_flatten(X,[X]) :- \+ is_list(X).
my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([H|T],R) :-
    my_flatten(H,HFlat),
    my_flatten(T,TFlat),
    append(HFlat,TFlat,R).
```

Some queries:

```
?- my_flatten([[]],R).
   R = [].

?- my_flatten([[1],[2]],R).
   R = [1, 2].

?- my_flatten([[1],[[3]]],R).
   R = [1, 3].
```

**EDIT**

As correctly observed by @lambda.xy.y, above version does not terminate for the query:

```
?- my_flatten(X,[X]).
```

So I took a look at the behaviour of SWI's built-in `flatten/2` and observed:

```
?- flatten([],[]).
   true.

?- flatten([],X).
   X = [].

?- flatten(X,[]).
   false.

?- flatten(X,Y).
   Y = [X].

?- flatten(X,[X]).
   true.
```

Implementation:

```
my_flatten(L,R) :-
    my_flatten(L,[],Flat),
    !,
    R=Flat.

my_flatten(X,R,[X|R])  :- \+ is_list(X), !.
my_flatten([],R,R)     :- !.
my_flatten([H|T],A1,R) :- !,
    my_flatten(H,A2,R),
    my_flatten(T,A1,A2).
my_flatten(NonList,T,[NonList|T]).
```

Comment: The query ```my_flatten(X,[X]).``` does not terminate (you can check this by querying ```my_flatten(X,[X]), false.```. In fact, after producing the solutions ```true``` and ```X=[X]```, there are no solutions found. (The requirement for termination was in the question)

Comment: @SeekAndDestroy unfortunately with your implementation (and to be fair with all my implementations so far) `my_flatten([X|B], [1, 2, 3, 4]).` and `my_flatten(A, [a, b, c]).` terminates with `false.` whereas `my_flatten1([X|B], [1, 2, 3, 4]).` and `my_flatten1(A, [a, b, c]).` produce all solutions.

Comment: I see what you mean, although looking at SWI Prolog's built-in `flatten/2`, we see it also returns false for those queries and doesn't generate all possibilities when given the most general query `flatten(X,Y)`.

Comment: @SeekAndDestroy: These are great reasons to show how broken `flatten/2` actually is! Do not use `flatten/2`. In most cases, you want `append/2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This straightforward implementation is not reversible, but it does not inccur in infinite loops. It will fail, instead.

```
flat2([],[]) :- 
    !.
flat2(X,[X]) :-
    X \= [_|_],
    !.
flat2([X|R],Result) :-
    flat2(X,XF),
    flat2(R,XR),
    append(XF,XR,Result).
```

Test:

```
?- flat2([[a,b],[c,[d,e,[f]]]],X).
X = [a, b, c, d, e, f].
```

Test (reverse):

```
?- flat2(X,[1,2]).
false.
?- flat2(X,[X]).
false.
```

It may be simplified, but this implementation is **not reversible** and will inccur in infinite loops in such case:

```
flat([X|R],Result) :-
    !,
    flat(X,XF),
    flat(R,XR),
    append(XF,XR,Result).

flat([],[]) :- !.
flat(X,[X]).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  :- [library(plunit)] .

  :- abolish(flatten/2) .
  :- mode(flatten(+,-)) .

  flatten(0,_) --> [Q] , flatten(1,Q) .
  flatten(1,Q) --> \+ {is_list(Q)} , flatten(2,Q) .
  flatten(1,Q) --> \+ \+ {is_list(Q)} , flatten(3,Q) .
  flatten(2,Q) , [Q] --> flatten(0,_) .
  flatten(3,Q) --> {Q=[]} , flatten(0,_) .
  flatten(3,Q) --> {Q=[R|Ts]} , flatten(1,R) , flatten(1,Ts) .

  :- begin_tests(flatten) .

  test('1',[true(Ps=[4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2])]) :-
  flatten([4,5,[6],[7,8,9],[1,2]],Ps) .

  test('2',[true(Ps=[1,2,3,4])]) :-
  flatten([1,[2,3],[],4],Ps) .

  test('3',[true(Ps=Qs)]) :-
  flatten(Qs,Ps) .

  :- end_tests(flatten) .
```

/*
sample run .

```
  ?- run_tests .

  % PL-Unit: flatten ... done               
  % All 3 tests passed

  ?- flatten([1,[2,3],[],4],Ps).
  Ps = [1,2,3,4].

  ?- flatten([4,5,[6],[7,8,9],[1,2]],Ps) .
  Ps = [4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2].

  ?- flatten(Qs,Ps) .
  Ps = [Qs].
```

*/